# How to get details for laravel sanctum

Tags: laravel, vue.js, jwt, laravel-sanctum

I know that with JWT, you can decode the token and get the details from it. In doing so you can validate in your standalone frontend app.(eg Vue js)

Is there a way to do the same thing with laravel sanctum with an SPA not on the same domain? If yes please how?

Comment: What do you mean with validating in the frontend? And are you looking to get the logged in user's details or what details do you want to get?

Comment: Yes I want to use the token to get  logged users details